# cassandra 2.0.11 multiple nodes on single windows machine

Tags: windows, multiple-instances, cassandra-2.0

I want to setup 3 nodes on windows machine for testing purpose. i already have community version installed. I followed some tutorials on youtube to setup 1 machine 3 nodes and docs as well. all 3 nodes are up but they are not connected. i can only see 1 node serving 100% load on "nodetool status"

Here is what i wanted, 3 instances connected as below

127.0.0.1 (seed)
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3

Here is what i did,

1. Installed Datastax community edition 2.0.11
2. Copied apache-cassandra/conf -> conf2 & conf3
3. modified cassandra.yaml for

   - cluster_name
   - seed_address (127.0.0.1)
   - listen_address (seed ip)
   - rpc_address 0.0.0.0
   - endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch

Above things were documented but i had to change below ports as it was single machine

- rpc_port:  [if default is 9160 then node1 will be 9161]
- native_transport_port:
- storage_port:

  4. Changed "JMX_PORT" in cassandra.bat file (created 2 copies of main file)
  5. started all

I tried ccm but its not picking already installed cassandra it tries to build from source and fails.

Am i missing something, it been 2 days (4-5 hours) i am trying to set this up.

Thanks, 
Ninad

Answer (score 0):

From my own tests, on Windows 7, 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.2 point to the same interface so you can't bind to the same port. Yet using different ports for each node, I had the same issue as you (nodes not communicating with each other). At the end I would recommend using Linux for this kind of tests, even a simple virtual machine, because for Linux 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 are not the same.

Comment: thanks for the pointers, i have started with setting up ubuntu vm struggling with getting 2 cassandra instances talking to each other i guess i messed up with seed address... thanks for the pointer..

Comment: I've managed to run CCM on Windows 7 but setup is un bit tricky.

Comment: If you change the IP of one node, I advise to 1) stop your cluster, 2) clear all your cluster data, 3) restart your cluster because Cassandra stores host information (like IP) in the database itself. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6615

Comment: i tried ccm but it fails to find the JAVA installed on machine, i tried with both 32 & 64 version of Java but ccm looks at different place, setting up JAVA_HOME is not solving the problem

Comment: I posted a detailed answer on how to create a local multi-node Cassandra cluster on Windows 7 here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34199571/181406